# Metrics Filters Resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

What resolution (basic monitoring with 5 min period, detailed with 1 min, or high-resolution with 1 sec) do Metric Filters use? And how can I change it or at least see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metric filters will only publish the data at 1min resolution.
As the data ages out, these will be rolled up into 5min (for data between 15d and 63d) then into 1h (for the remaining 15 months).

This follows the normal metric retention policy as described in the question "What is the retention period of all metrics?" in the [CloudWatch FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/faqs/).

AFAIK subminute resolution is not supported at the moment for metric filters.

Comment: So does that mean that if I use Metric Filters I will use and will be billed for a Standard Resolution Metrics, right? And also what if Metric Filters see in logs two or more log messages that will trigger them? For example if I send **3 separate log events** during one min period about the number of players in a room three times in a row with "3, 5, 7" data. **How then these three numbers that will be read by Metrics Filters are then aggreagated and send to Metrics?**

Comment: you will be charged for your CWL traffic + CloudWatch metrics (as standard resolution metrics), yes.
When you produce logs that have data for the same minute, that data will be aggregated automatically for you on the metrics side by CloudWatch.
In your particular example, you will have a avg= 5, min=3, max =7 sampleCount=3

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I think I understand it))